# std::vector with nested template argument

Tags: c++, vector

i quite new to C++. A'm using std::map with GCC. Since (in my opinion) std::map output with GDB is hard to read. I'd like to export my map to a vector.

Now i already figured out (with some helpful posts from this forum) :) how to export map to a vector. Now i'f i uderstood the c++ reference correctly std::map is not thread safe. So i build a Mutex arround std::map

```
template<typename Mutex_Type_T, typename Key_Type_T, typename Mapped_Type_T>
class CConcurrent_Dictionary
{

public:

    CConcurrent_Dictionary();

    class CSingle_Element
    {
    public:

        Key_Type_T key = { };

        Mapped_Type_T mapped_type = { };

    };

    /**
     * Exports all contect of std::map to a vector
     * @param mutex_timeout Mutex timeout
     * @return Vector with all contents of std::map
     */
    std::vector<CSingle_Element> Export(const uint32_t mutex_timeout) const;

private:
    const Mutex_Type_T mutex;

    map<Key_Type_T, Mapped_Type_T> dictionary;
};
```

The implementation of Export() looks like this

```
template<typename Mutex_Type_T, typename Key_Type_T, typename Mapped_Type_T>
std::vector<CConcurrent_Dictionary<Mutex_Type_T, Key_Type_T, Mapped_Type_T>::CSingle_Element> CConcurrent_Dictionary<Mutex_Type_T, Key_Type_T, Mapped_Type_T>::Export(const uint32_t mutex_timeout) const
{
    std::vector<CSingle_Element> res = {};
    CLock_Guard_New<Mutex_Type_T> lock(mutex);
    if(false == lock.Lock(mutex_timeout))
    {
        return res;
    }


    //export all Elements
    for(const auto& single_element : dictionary)
    {
        CSingle_Element single = {};
        single.key = single_element.first;
        single.mapped_type = single_element.second;
        res.push_back(single);
    }

    return res;
}
```

However the problem fails to compile

```
note:   expected a type, got 'NDictionary::CConcurrent_Dictionary<Mutex_Type_T, Key_Type_T, Mapped_Type_T>::CSingle_Element'
 error: template argument 2 is invalid
 error: prototype for 'int NDictionary::CConcurrent_Dictionary<Mutex_Type_T, Key_Type_T, Mapped_Type_T>::Export(uint32_t) const' does not match any in class 'NDictionary::CConcurrent_Dictionary<Mutex_Type_T, Key_Type_T, Mapped_Type_T>'
```

It looks like the vector template argument are not taken correctly.

For my understanding I'd expect

**CConcurrent_Dictionary::CSingle_Element**
to be the only template argument to std::vector. So could you help me out? What am i missing?

Comment: Aside: All those codes are easier to read than using a `std::map` container?

Comment: where would a add typename? I tried ```typename vector<...>...``` and ```vector<typename ...>...```. @Amadeus: Are you suggesting i shoudl write my own container? The class is supposed to be used in a multithreaded environment. So i need to protect std::map right?

Comment: Alternately, if you use a trailing return type, you don't need the class scope before `CSingle_Element`: `template <...> auto CConcurrentDictionary::Mutex_Type_T, Key_Type_T, Mapped_Type_T>::Export(const uint32_t mutex_timeout) const -> std::vector<CSingle_Element> { ... }`

Comment: @aschepler thx this did help me. However a cannot vote for your post yet. [at]all Thx for your fast replys

Answer (score 1):

Try following: `std::vector<typename CConcurrent_Dictionary<Mutex_Type_T, Key_Type_T, Mapped_Type_T>::CSingle_Element>`

Comment: hey this causes i syntax problem. I cannot figure out what the problem is. However i decided to go with aschepler answer :)